# What is best way for sending data to another Application

Tags: java, web-services, java-ee-7

I wrote `servlet`,If any one triggers this `servlet`,`.exe` file will be run and does some computations and finally returns `.txt` files as a output and triggers another Application(`Application 2`).

While triggering time, I need to send `.txt` files data to `Application 2` as a input. Actually `Application 2` is not sending any request to `Application 1`.

I did up to `.exe` running. Now I want to trigger another Application with `.txt` file data.

Note :

`.txt` file have more than 3,00,000 co-ordinate points.

Before start this work, I need to know which way is better.Initially I think webservices  useful but `Application 2` not sending any request to `Application 1`. SO `WebServices` concept also not useful.

Is there any better way for this.

Could somebody point me to some good documentation about how to do this ?

I hope, you understand what am I expecting.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the second application does not send any response back to the first application?

Comment: Yes, Second Application does not send any response to first Application.

Comment: Is application 2 like a server application that runs independently on a separate machine or is it a binary executable? How does it expect to receive the data?

Comment: @Joni `Application 2` is a server Application. Still we didn't start `Application 2`. we develop `Application` using either `Wolfram Mathematica` or `Java`.

Comment: So how does application 2 obtain the data it needs?

Comment: @Joni once we decided data transfer, we will implement that type of logic in `Application 2`.